# Combine multiple spark dataframe rows into one based on other columns i.e. applying CDC

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, databricks

I have data in below form in my spark dataframe.

```
        +----+------+------+------+-----------+-------------------------+
        | id | name | age  | city | operation | update_time             |
        +----+------+------+------+-----------+-------------------------+
        | 1  | jon  | 12   | NULL | INSERT    | 2021-10-11T16:11:00.378 |
        +----+------+------+------+-----------+-------------------------+
        | 1  | NULL | NULL | NY   | UPDATE    | 2021-10-11T17:11:00.378 |
        +----+------+------+------+-----------+-------------------------+
        | 1  | jack | NULL | NULL | UPDATE    | 2021-10-11T18:11:00.378 |
        +----+------+------+------+-----------+-------------------------+
        | 2  | sam  | 11   | TN   | INSERT    | 2021-10-11T18:11:00.378 |
        +----+------+------+------+-----------+-------------------------+
        | 3  | tim  | NULL | CA   | INSERT    | 2021-10-11T16:11:00.378 |
        +----+------+------+------+-----------+-------------------------+
        | 3  | NULL | 33   | MT   | UPDATE    | 2021-10-11T17:11:00.378 |
        +----+------+------+------+-----------+-------------------------+
```

I am trying to look for functions in dataframe that can help me transform the data into below form. But didn't find anything. The most I can think of is joins but it should be with multiple dataframe. But here I have only one. So how to collapse the rows to one and include all the updated column values into one row.

```
+----+------+-----+------+-------------------------+
| id | name | age | city | update_time             |
+----+------+-----+------+-------------------------+
| 1  | jack | 12  | NY   | 2021-10-11T18:11:00.378 |
+----+------+-----+------+-------------------------+
| 2  | sam  | 11  | TN   | 2021-10-11T18:11:00.378 |
+----+------+-----+------+-------------------------+
| 3  | tim  | 33  | MT   | 2021-10-11T17:11:00.378 |
+----+------+-----+------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: I think it would be easy to code up something using window functions and `last` with your sample data (I mean, I did code something up that worked for your sample data) but I think it's too simplistic.  How can you assume all records will always have an INSERT for example?  I think this would be unlikely in a CDC scenario.  Aren't you going to need to compare with the master table and not just the dataframe?  You probably should take a look at [Delta Lake](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/quick-start.html) instead.

Comment: Yes you are right, there can be a scenario where I have only UPDATE and no INSERT operation. But I cannot connect to the database for the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
package spark

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object DataFrameWindowFunc extends App {

  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("DataFrame-WindowFunction")
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  case class Data(
      id: Int,
      name: Option[String],
      age: Option[Int],
      city: Option[String],
      operation: String,
      updateTime: String
  )

  val sourceData = Seq(
    Data(1, Some("jon"), Some(12), None, "INSERT", "2021-10-11T16:11:00.378"),
    Data(1, None, None, Some("NY"), "UPDATE", "2021-10-11T17:11:00.378"),
    Data(1, Some("jack"), None, None, "UPDATE", "2021-10-11T18:11:00.378"),
    Data(
      2,
      Some("sam"),
      Some(11),
      Some("TN"),
      "INSERT",
      "2021-10-11T18:11:00.378"
    ),
    Data(3, Some("tim"), None, Some("CA"), "INSERT", "2021-10-11T16:11:00.378"),
    Data(3, None, Some(33), Some("MT"), "UPDATE", "2021-10-11T17:11:00.378")
  ).toDF

  sourceData.show(false)
  //      +---+----+----+----+---------+-----------------------+
  //      |id |name|age |city|operation|updateTime             |
  //      +---+----+----+----+---------+-----------------------+
  //      |1  |jon |12  |null|INSERT   |2021-10-11T16:11:00.378|
  //      |1  |null|null|NY  |UPDATE   |2021-10-11T17:11:00.378|
  //      |1  |jack|null|null|UPDATE   |2021-10-11T18:11:00.378|
  //      |2  |sam |11  |TN  |INSERT   |2021-10-11T18:11:00.378|
  //      |3  |tim |null|CA  |INSERT   |2021-10-11T16:11:00.378|
  //      |3  |null|33  |MT  |UPDATE   |2021-10-11T17:11:00.378|
  //      +---+----+----+----+---------+-----------------------+

  val res = sourceData
    .orderBy(col("id"), col("updateTime").desc)
    .groupBy("id")
    .agg(
      first(col("name"), true).alias("name"),
      first(col("age"), true).alias("age"),
      first(col("city"), true).alias("city"),
      first(col("updateTime"), true).alias("update_time")
    )
    .orderBy(col("id"))
  res.show(false)
  //  +---+----+---+----+-----------------------+
  //  |id |name|age|city|update_time            |
  //  +---+----+---+----+-----------------------+
  //  |1  |jack|12 |NY  |2021-10-11T18:11:00.378|
  //  |2  |sam |11 |TN  |2021-10-11T18:11:00.378|
  //  |3  |tim |33 |MT  |2021-10-11T17:11:00.378|
  //  +---+----+---+----+-----------------------+

}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me a direction, so if understand the code correctly it will pick the first() one in the group that is ordered by updated_time desc irrespective of Operation. So if the operation is all update still it will group all rows and make it as a one row? Sorry but I am new to scala and spark so it takes time to understand the code.

Comment: yes. one row to every id.

Comment: ok but what line of code is doing the magic of collapsing the column values  and picking the latest one. For example jon and jack

Comment: orderBy(...) - give sort with last to first line for id and insert/update time. 
groupBy(...) - one line for group id. 
first(col, true) - give first value column for group if not null.  
Using agg() function, we can calculate more than one aggregate at a time.